# How To Fix duplicate entry Error in a mysqldb- pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, mysql-python

I´m learning and trying raise an app with pyqt5, which insert a data in my database. Sometimes an existing id number (primary key) is typed and the program fall... I have created the next code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, 
QPushButton, QMessageBox
import sys
import MySQLdb as mdb 

class Window(QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title = "PyQt5 Insert Data"        
    self.top = 100        
    self.left = 100        
    self.width = 680        
    self.height = 400
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon_health.png"))

    self.InitWindow()

  def InitWindow(self):

    self.linedit0 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.linedit0.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your ID')
    self.linedit0.setGeometry(200,50,200,30)

    self.linedit1 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.linedit1.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your name')
    self.linedit1.setGeometry(200,100,200,30)

    self.linedit2 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.linedit2.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your email')
    self.linedit2.setGeometry(200,150,200,30)

    self.linedit3 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.linedit3.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your phone')
    self.linedit3.setGeometry(200,200,200,30)

    self.button = QPushButton("Insert data", self)
    self.button.setGeometry(200,250,100,30)
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.Insertdata)

    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon_health.png"))
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
    self.show()

 def Insertdata (self):
    con = mdb.connect("localhost","root","xxxx","dbname")
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO data (id, name, email, phone)" 
                     "VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')" % (''.join(self.linedit0.text()),
                                                 ''.join(self.linedit1.text()),
                                                 ''.join(self.linedit2.text()),
                                                 ''.join(self.linedit3.text())))
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Connection","Data Inserted Sucessfully")
        self.close()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

The app run nice, but when i type a duplicate ID enter (primary key) the program fall and advertize:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\oscar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Users\oscar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorvalue
File "C:\Users\oscar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
res = self._query(query)
File "C:\Users\oscar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
rowcount = self._do_query(q)
File "C:\Users\oscar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
db.query(q)
File "C:\Users\oscar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '#######' for key 
'PRIMARY'")
[Finished in 13.2s]
```

That´s a litle very frustrating for me. I have intentend a solution:

```
try:
   con = mdb.connect("localhost", "root", "xxxxx", "dbname") 
except _mysql.Error as e: 
   QMessageBox.about(self,"Connection", "Duplicate entry for ID")
   sys.exit()
```

But the output remain the same. I would appreciatte your help

Comment: Maybe try _mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError in your except clause.

Answer (score 0):

`id` an auto increment column you don't need the value for key primary.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO data (name, email, phone)" 
                     "VALUES('%s','%s','%s')" % (
                                                 ''.join(self.linedit1.text()),
                                                 ''.join(self.linedit2.text()),
                                                 ''.join(self.linedit3.text())))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but suppose you, if the value is your social security identification...

Comment: Create a field for these purposes, for example `id_social`.
Field `id` - Primary key (primary key) is one of the examples of unique indexes and is used to uniquely identify table entries. None of the two table entries can have the same primary key values.